# can i use jaguardb to process stream data?

Tags: database, stream

I have some sensor stream data, can I use jaguardb to store them?

the data is stream based, i want to store hourly stats and daily stats.
is jaguardb good to store and process such data.

no code

Answer (score 0):

You can create the hourly table, the daily table in jaguardb. When you update the hourly table, you can rollup the stats at the start of day to the daily table.